# Chrome paused in Debugger only on specific website

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging

I have the following problem: My Debugger is always paused but only at: https://www.supremenewyork.com/mobile/ . It is just this website where it is paused. Does anybody know how to fix it?

Comment: Remove all the breakpoints. Close development tools if not debugging then the breakpoint won't hit. The statement might contain a `debug;` keyword. This will force the breakpoint to hit.

Comment: How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You had written `debugger;` in code that's why it pause there every time 
remove that `debugger;`.

[image]

Comment: How can I remove it?

Comment: Most commonly debugger is return in .js file. In your case it seems to be in file like  **VM728**. and one more thing your debugger; work in only in debugger mode.  the another option is that don't open in your debugger mode until it necessary.

Comment: Can u help me to remove it. I dont know where I can find the file VM728?

Comment: Check in  all your .js file  for** debugger;**  and remove it